# Rmarkdown - code run ok at script, but when knit gives error

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have one Rmarkdown document, that was given to me and worked fine with the person who given to me.
But when I do with my datas, I dont know what's going on, when I run the exactly code with script document works well, but when I try to knit to html, give me an error.

```
bhv_df <- plyr::ddply(bhv_df, ~segmentid, function(d){
  d= bhv_df[bhv_df$segmentid == bhv_df$segmentid[1], 
  # predictions are made based on the mid time between start and end of the message
  predObj <- crawl::crwPredict(object.crwFit = crawl_models_list[[d$segmentid[1]]], predTime = d$MidTime, speedEst=TRUE, flat=TRUE)
  predObj_dives <- predObj[predObj$locType == "p",]
  # reproject into lat/long, because the crawl models have been built in a mercator pacific centered CRS
  coord_points <- predObj_dives
  coordinates(coord_points) =~ mu.x + mu.y
  proj4string(coord_points) <- CRS("+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
  predObj_dives[c("lon", "lat")] <- coordinates(spTransform(coord_points, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))
  # calculate the lon360
  return(cbind(d, predObj_dives[c("mu.x", "mu.y", "lon", "lat")]))
})


#load("./Outputs/crawl_argos_df.RData")

######### MERGE DIVE DATASET with CRAWL-derived MOUVEMENT DATA
bhv_df <- plyr::ddply(bhv_df, ~segmentid, function(d){ # for each tag dive data
  cr <- crawl_argos_df[crawl_argos_df$segmentid == d$segmentid[1], ] # select the corresponding crawl track
  fl <- filtered_argos_df_crawl[filtered_argos_df_crawl$segmentid == d$segmentid[1], ] # select the corresponding filtered track
  d[c("lq_closest_filt","dt_closest_filt", "dist_closest_filt", "rel.angle","speed")] <- NA # add empty columns
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)){ # for each dive...
    fl$dist_diff <- as.vector(spDists(x = as.matrix(d[i,c("lon", "lat")]), y = as.matrix(fl[c("lon", "lat")]), longlat = T)) # distance calculated in km
    fl$dt_diff <- as.numeric(difftime(d$MidTime[i], fl$time, units = "hours"))
    d[i, "dt_closest_filt"] <- min(abs(fl$dt_diff)) # select the filtered position closest in time to the dive, time in hours
    d[i, "dist_closest_filt"] <- fl[which(abs(fl$dt_diff) == min(abs(fl$dt_diff))), "dist_diff"][1] # retrieve the distance from this filtered position to the dive location (predicted by crawl)
    d[i, "lq_closest_filt"] <- fl[which(abs(fl$dt_diff) == min(abs(fl$dt_diff))), "lq"][1] # argos quality of closest filtered argos position
    cr$diff <- as.numeric(difftime(d$MidTime[i], cr$time, units = "hours")) # look at the time diff between this dive and all positions recorded in crawl for that same tag
    d[i, c("rel.angle","speed")] <- cr[abs(cr$diff) == min(abs(cr$diff)), c("rel.angle", "speed")] # select closest position recorded when dive occurred
  }
  return(d)
})

bhv_df$depth_bin <- cut(bhv_df$DepthMean, seq(0, 700, 50))

ggplot(bhv_df[bhv_df$What == "Dive" & bhv_df$depth_range == "deep" & bhv_df$DepthMean < 1000,], aes(x = lon, y = lat)) +
  stat_contour(data = bathyNOAA_df, aes(x, y, z=z), binwidth = 500, color = "grey60", size = 0.2) +
  geom_tile(data = bathyNOAA_df_shallow[bathyNOAA_df_shallow$z >= 0, ], aes(x, y), fill = "grey10") +
  geom_jitter(aes(fill = -DepthMean, size = DepthMean), col="black", alpha=0.8, pch = 21, width=0.1) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "magma", name = "Dive Depth (m)", direction = 1, begin = 0.2) +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-50, -26), ylim = c(-55, -15), expand = F)
```

The error (is it just at beginning of the code, at 4 line):

> Erro: unexpected symbol in:
>   "  predObj <- crawl::crwPredict(object.crwFit = crawl_models_list[[d$segmentid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaCKo.png)]], predTime = d$MidTime, speedEst=TRUE, flat=TRUE)
>     predObj_dives"

And this:

[image]

I tryed to see if have conflicts, but apparently dont have

```
> conflicts()
 [1] "lines"         "cividis"       "inferno"       "magma"         "plasma"        "viridis"       "viridis.map"  
 [8] "summary"       "days"          "hours"         "minutes"       "origin"        "seconds"       "show"         
[15] "years"         "hour"          "isoweek"       "mday"          "minute"        "month"         "quarter"      
[22] "second"        "wday"          "week"          "yday"          "year"          "coerce"        "coerce"       
[29] "plot"          "show"          "summary"       "%>%"           "%>%"           "%>%"           "between"      
[36] "count"         "first"         "intersect"     "last"          "setdiff"       "union"         "%>%"          
[43] "flatten"       "map"           "transpose"     "%>%"           "add_row"       "as_data_frame" "as_tibble"    
[50] "data_frame"    "data_frame_"   "frame_data"    "glimpse"       "lst"           "lst_"          "tbl_sum"      
[57] "tibble"        "tribble"       "trunc_mat"     "type_sum"      "enexpr"        "enexprs"       "enquo"        
[64] "enquos"        "ensym"         "ensyms"        "expr"          "quo"           "quo_name"      "quos"         
[71] "sym"           "syms"          "vars"          "filter"        "lag"           "lines"         "plot"         
[78] "as.raster"     "data"          "Arith"         "coerce"        "Compare"       "initialize"    "show"         
[85] "as.difftime"   "body<-"        "date"          "intersect"     "kronecker"     "merge"         "Position"     
[92] "setdiff"       "setequal"      "split"         "subset"        "summary"       "union"        
>
```

Someone know what's going on?
Thanks!

Comment: This line seems to be unfinished: `d= bhv_df[bhv_df$segmentid == bhv_df$segmentid[1],`.

Comment: I'd advise you to clear your environment and unload all libraries before running this code and also clearing all caches. Sometimes environment variables are inherited by knitr when none is generated by it with the same name, and cache may also keep old results. This should help you reproduce same environment and discover the error.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent , the code is this way, and works well in script document

Comment: @user2332849 , I already did this, and created an new Rmarkdown document, and I until restarted my computer...

Comment: I agree that the line is unfinished `d= bhv_df[bhv_df$segmentid == bhv_df$segmentid[1]`, probably just needs an `]` at the end, that was deleted maybe by previous owner. There is no matching bracket. Cannot possibly work this way.

Comment: when I put the `]`, it works, but not in the correct way .. the code after that, which is a map (I updated the code above), which shows the result of this function, is not right. But when I run without the `]` in the normal script, it works, but when I try the knit that error results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I removed one part of the code, and everything worked well

```
# I removed: d= bhv_df[bhv_df$segmentid == bhv_df$segmentid[1], 

bhv_df <- plyr::ddply(bhv_df, ~segmentid, function(d){
  # predictions are made based on the mid time between start and end of the message
  predObj <- crawl::crwPredict(object.crwFit = crawl_models_list[[d$segmentid[1]]], predTime = d$MidTime, speedEst=TRUE, flat=TRUE)
  predObj_dives <- predObj[predObj$locType == "p",]
  # reproject into lat/long, because the crawl models have been built in a mercator pacific centered CRS
  coord_points <- predObj_dives
  coordinates(coord_points) =~ mu.x + mu.y
  proj4string(coord_points) <- CRS("+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
  predObj_dives[c("lon", "lat")] <- coordinates(spTransform(coord_points, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))
  # calculate the lon360
  return(cbind(d, predObj_dives[c("mu.x", "mu.y", "lon", "lat")]))
})


######### MERGE DIVE DATASET with CRAWL-derived MOUVEMENT DATA
bhv_df <- plyr::ddply(bhv_df, ~segmentid, function(d){ # for each tag dive data
  cr <- crawl_argos_df[crawl_argos_df$segmentid == d$segmentid[1], ] # select the corresponding crawl track
  fl <- filtered_argos_df_crawl[filtered_argos_df_crawl$segmentid == d$segmentid[1], ] # select the corresponding filtered track
  d[c("lq_closest_filt","dt_closest_filt", "dist_closest_filt", "rel.angle","speed")] <- NA # add empty columns
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)){ # for each dive...
    fl$dist_diff <- as.vector(spDists(x = as.matrix(d[i,c("lon", "lat")]), y = as.matrix(fl[c("lon", "lat")]), longlat = T)) # distance calculated in km
    fl$dt_diff <- as.numeric(difftime(d$MidTime[i], fl$time, units = "hours"))
    d[i, "dt_closest_filt"] <- min(abs(fl$dt_diff)) # select the filtered position closest in time to the dive, time in hours
    d[i, "dist_closest_filt"] <- fl[which(abs(fl$dt_diff) == min(abs(fl$dt_diff))), "dist_diff"][1] # retrieve the distance from this filtered position to the dive location (predicted by crawl)
    d[i, "lq_closest_filt"] <- fl[which(abs(fl$dt_diff) == min(abs(fl$dt_diff))), "lq"][1] # argos quality of closest filtered argos position
    cr$diff <- as.numeric(difftime(d$MidTime[i], cr$time, units = "hours")) # look at the time diff between this dive and all positions recorded in crawl for that same tag
    d[i, c("rel.angle","speed")] <- cr[abs(cr$diff) == min(abs(cr$diff)), c("rel.angle", "speed")] # select closest position recorded when dive occurred
  }
  return(d)
}) #warnings probably due to RT being equal to NA at beginning and end of the track
```

Thank you